# VS 2015 crash - Possibly related to Code Analysis

Tags: crash, visual-studio-2015

I have a clean installation of VS 2015 Enterprise. Every time I create a new Console Application project VS crashes. Sometimes it displays a dialog box saying that VS has crashed, but most of the time the IDE just disappears. This error is logged in the event log.

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string message).
Message: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.
   at System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection`1.get_Count()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CSharp.NavigationBar.CSharpNavigationBarItemService.GetTypesInFile(SemanticModel semanticModel, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CSharp.NavigationBar.CSharpNavigationBarItemService.<GetTypesInFileAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CSharp.NavigationBar.CSharpNavigationBarItemService.<GetItemsAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.NavigationBar.NavigationBarController.<ComputeModelAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.
   at System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection`1.get_Count()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CSharp.NavigationBar.CSharpNavigationBarItemService.GetTypesInFile(SemanticModel semanticModel, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CSharp.NavigationBar.CSharpNavigationBarItemService.<GetTypesInFileAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CSharp.NavigationBar.CSharpNavigationBarItemService.<GetItemsAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.NavigationBar.NavigationBarController.<ComputeModelAsync>d__30.MoveNext()<---

Stack:
   at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FailFast.OnFatalException(System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ErrorReporting.FatalError.Report(System.Exception, System.Action`1<System.Exception>)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ErrorReporting.FatalError.Report(System.Exception)
   at Roslyn.Utilities.TaskExtensions.ReportFatalErrorWorker(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.TryExecuteTaskInline(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.TryRunInline(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuation.InlineIfPossibleOrElseQueue(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation.Run(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ContinueWithCore(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler, System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuationOptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ContinueWith(System.Action`2<System.Threading.Tasks.Task,System.Object>, System.Object, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler, System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuationOptions, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ContinueWith(System.Action`2<System.Threading.Tasks.Task,System.Object>, System.Object, System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuationOptions, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler)
   at Roslyn.Utilities.TaskExtensions.ReportFatalError(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.TryExecuteTaskInline(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.TryRunInline(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuation.InlineIfPossibleOrElseQueue(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.StandardTaskContinuation.Run(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetException(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetFromTask(System.Threading.Tasks.Task, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Invoke(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetException(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetException(System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.NavigationBar.NavigationBarController+<ComputeModelAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetException(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetException(System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CSharp.NavigationBar.CSharpNavigationBarItemService+<GetItemsAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetException(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetException(System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.CSharp.NavigationBar.CSharpNavigationBarItemService+<GetTypesInFileAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.__Canon)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document+<GetSemanticModelAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.__Canon)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker+<GetOrBuildCompilationAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.__Canon)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker+<BuildCompilationFromScratchAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.__Canon)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution+CompilationTracker+<BuildDeclarationCompilationFromScratchAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.__Canon)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DocumentState+<GetSyntaxTreeAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action, Boolean, System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SetResult(System.__Canon)
   at Roslyn.Utilities.AsyncLazy`1+Request[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].CompleteFromTaskSynchronously(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.__Canon>)
   at Roslyn.Utilities.AsyncLazy`1+Request[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].CompleteFromTaskSynchronouslyStub(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

I get the exact same error if I open an existing project and try to open a CS file.

I have been struggling with this for the last two days. I've repaired the installation numerous time. I've done multiple uninstall/installs using different ISO files. I've trawled the internet looking for similar issues without success.

Has anyone come across this before? Any ideas where to go from here?

I've tried logging it as bug on connect.microsoft.com but that site always craps out before I can even start the process.

Thanks,

David

Comment: EntryPointNotFoundException is a broken machine problem.  You've got a DLL that is corrupted, usually a problem with the disk drive.  Get another one.

Comment: SFC /SCANNOW seems to confirm that there are corrupted files on the disk. I'll talk to our IT guys about getting a new disk. Thanks for that.