# Visual studio freezing /hanging - out of memory

Tags: visual-studio-2015

My visual studio 2015 is hanging/freezing all the time lately, started recently out of nowhere.

It does come back into play usually but sometimes I get a System.OutOfMemoryException error even though it doesn't appear to be going anywhere near my limit!

In my windows event logs I can see errors like this

```
    Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.25420.1, time stamp: 0x57685d85
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0x80131623
Fault offset: 0x052f0e74
Faulting process id: 0x22e4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3f73901ba00fd
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: b9c4e928-6263-4eb6-8319-d6bcc05d239e
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

OR

```
devenv (8604,D,0) 201b6ea9-a2dc-4eb7-93df-3b89ae574335: Database 'C:\.....dbmdl': Background clean-up skipped pages. The database may benefit from widening the online maintenance window during off-peak hours. If this message persists, offline defragmentation may be run to remove all skipped pages from the database.
```

I've tried deleting the dbmdl but that didn't make a difference...

Comment: 0x80131623 is generated by Environment.FailFast(), merely more evidence that something is Really, Really Wrong.  Probably nothing that a disk reformat couldn't fix (check the disk first), you might save time by spinning the repair/reinstall wheel of fortune.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yeah I have kicked off the repair!  I went into to VS to check for updates and got an error then so figured time to try the repair

Comment: Did a repair on visual studio, sadly no fix :/

Comment: Try my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46828662/vs2015-crashes-when-opening-cs-file/57070475#57070475